# Google App Engine - Development Server - Not accessible from other machines

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've read the posts around here about the above topic and have set an argument -a 0.0.0.0 and port 8888 in the arguments of the app engine project. I'm able to open up http://10.0.1.X:8888 on the machine on which app engine is being run. However, from the other machine if I use the same address in a browser, I get an error "This web page is not available". All my machines are on the same wi-fi network. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a firewall configuration problem. Also, check that the machine is reachable from other machines in the network (e.g. ping).

Comment: Note that a ping failure does not mean that the 8888 port is unreachable though, since some machines block ICMP (ping protocol).

Comment: I'm able to ping the machine IP address without any issues. my firewall is also off within the private network. :(

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed a firewall problem. Even after switching it off, I needed a restart :)